# How to add CI/CD in Flutter existing Android app

Tags: android, flutter, continuous-integration

We have added Flutter in existing native Android. now we have two repositories,`Flutter_module` and  `Android_module`. I am using `GitLab` for `CI/CD` pipeline.
 problem is how to set `include_flutter.groovy` path in `setting.gradle` because it is in another repository.